# Is there a good way to say "don't use constructor" in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a constructor who's general purpose is to be used by a library that uses reflection (so it has to be public). It's also used by a static factory that's meant for people to use if they need it (but also isn't exported beyond the directory, because that shouldn't be needed). Is there a good way to communicate "don't use this"? bonus points if it's a way that the IDE will recognize.

Comment: Make the constructor private? Why would it matter what the access modifier is for reflection?

Comment: To be clear: the goal is to either document, or type-check against, that certain other code shouldn't use the constructor? Well - what if someone wants to write a different static factory? What if someone else has a valid use for reflection? (For that matter: if using the constructor is interfered with by a type-checker, why wouldn't that equally cause a problem when the reflection-using library wants to invoke it?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel don't really care if something uses reflection, also using `private` doesn't make the JS private. If someone needs to write another one that's fine, I just don't want it exposed outside of the "package" (not that we're using modules or namespaces... which might solve the problem)

Comment: @VLAZ the problem of course is reflection where you have to pass `TheClass` to something. a private constructor can't be used by typescript. Which is unfortunate since I think `new TheClass()` should be different from `foo(TheClass)`

Comment: Then I don't know what you're trying to do but doesn't sound like "reflection" to me.

Comment: @VLAZ code doing  reflection often needs the class as a parameter. I mean, how else would you look at the class to find things out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't export it in index (i.e. as `import .. from 'my-library'`) but in extra files (i.e. `import .. from 'my-library/internal.js'`)
2. Make it `/** @deprecated */`, then the editor will strikethrough it
3. Don't write about it in the readme

Choose any you like

Comment: yeah, I thought about deprecated... probably my best bet. The class (I think), may need export for other usage, just not `new`. since this is corporateware, the readme is irrelevant. I did want to use `@internal` and keep it out of the .d.ts, but I think that we're not using those...

Comment: Or you may try exporting class as `abstract` so one can't instantiate it (dunno how exactly that works tho)

Comment: If this is an answer please mark it as such @xenoterracide

Comment: it is an *answer* is it *the* answer... idk. best answer given. I guess it's the one right now. Seems like a sucky situation